# Integrate viro-react into react-native project

Tags: react-native

Anyone here managed to integrate `viro-react` into `react-native` project? I followed the instruction in 
the [documentation](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/integrating-with-react-native-projects)

After that, I executed the project but not able to run.

This is the error that I got
[image]

Even though I run with gradlew installOvrDebug, still it failed.

Comment: hi @Mr.T so do u have any experience in using viro-react?

Answer (score 1):

If your configurations are correct then try running with any of these variants
   **ArDebug, GvrDebug** or **OvrDebug**

Example running apllication with **Augmented Reality**:

Android

```
 react-native run-android --variant=ArDebug
```

iOS

```
react-native run-ios --variant=ArDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following method:

1. Go to the Navigate to the **node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js** file and edit the lines that include *installDebug* change it to *installArDebug*
2. Go to the terminal and npm start
3. Open another terminal and react-native run-android

*Make sure that your device is plugged in and that you have android studio sdk paths in your environment variables. This should do the trick!